# How to get data from TextBox, which located on the other page?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I have `MainPaqe.cs` (`MainPaqe.xaml`) and `Periodic_Request.cs` (`Periodic_Request.xaml`), in addition, `Periodic_Request.xaml` has `TextBox` with name `TxtBlock_numRequest` and `Combobox` with name `CmbBox_lvlPriority` with possible 3 options.

The problem is how get user written numbers or strings from `TextBox` and `Combobox` in the `MainPaqe.cs`. I need to get all this information after pressing `button`.

Someone has advised to use `MVVM` , but honestly I can`t understand it. This is why I need your help.

Comment: You deleted and re asked the exact same question from before ,
but you haven't posted any XAML or any code .. 
It's important if you wan't a solution

Comment: Yes, you right, but I have improved it, to make it more simple

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`MVVM` is an architectural design pattern which facilitates the `Separation of Concerns` design pattern.  It is highly advantageous to make use of the `MVVM` pattern when developing your `WPF` applications although not compulsory.  Implementing the `MVVM` pattern in your application can require a little more effort and thought, at least when first using it, than is required when using `WPF` the old `WinForms` `code-behind` way.

> 1) If you want to go down the `MVVM` route, take a look at the `EventAggregator` and `Mediator\Message Bus` patterns.  These allow `classes` to communicate with one another without them requiring direct knowledge of one another.
>
> 2) Alternatively if you are happy to continue using the `WinForms` route, take a look at the `EventHandler<T>` delegate.  This will allow you to raise an `event` in one `class` which can be detected by another `class`.

Comment: I`m using WPF, so I guess, the only way out is to use first variant?

Comment: @Rocketq - You can use the latter variant, the `WinForms` route simply refers to that you use the `code-behind` `cs` file to power your `xaml` view rather than a `decoupled` `ViewModel` as defined in the `MVVM` design pattern.